# Naudio - Create effects hosting with VST3

Tags: hosting, naudio, effects, vst

I have created a multitrack recording app using c#.  I am at the point in the coding where I need to create my effects inserts.  I downloaded and installed the VST-SDKs (several from 2.x and 3.x).  Of course, these SDKs are in c++.  I also installed the VST.Net library which seem to only work with 2.x.  It is a c#, NET interface to VST 2.x.  It seems to have a beginning to a 3.x interface in the Source3 directory - not sure it was finished.  Anyway, I am looking for recommendations on getting a quick start to setting up a VST host in Naudio.  I understand (somewhat) the managed-unmanaged issues and latency problems.  I think other products using Naudio must have found ways to accomplish this task.  Any advice or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You are correct about VST.NET. It is VST2.x only. The VST3.x code that you see is unfinished. I am not aware of any other libraries that support VST3.x. (author of VST.NET) [2c]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you obiwanjacobi!  I am going to start with your Clr4 code to come up to speed on VST2.x and tackle VST3x after that.  I have successfully built all the main code and samples for Clr4 with Visual Studio 2019 professional.  The only one that I have not successfully built yet is the StereoMeltor project.  Namely, the PluginEditView which seems to have some late binding XML code for the Parameter Manager.  I think this might just be a VS 2019 issue with some changing support for XML in VS 2019. Anyway, I can figure it out.  Thank you for your excellent work on this code and your exemplary commitment to the open source community!